# Ruby on rails internationalization for Spanish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm creating a fast application with ruby on rails, and after doing a lot of scaffolding and validation I'm very happy with some of the features that are embeded in RoR... but I live in Mexico and all my users would love the application to be in Spanish of course. So, I noticed theres a lot of functions that write actual text in English for example time_ago_in_words and all the errors produced by the scaffolding and validation.

Before actually doing those things on my own (like I would in php for example) I wanted to know if theres some kind of language file I could edit (or even download one in Spanish). After all, the books I'm reading and the tutorials (and webcast) I'm following to learn this new framework are all in English (and fail to include this problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you can find a nice [sample app](http://github.com/karmi/rails_i18n_demo_app/tree/master) which demonstrates some basics of i18n (internationalization features) in Rails.

Answer (score 7):

This guide contains the most recent work on internationalization. A pretty decent reference:
http://guides.rails.info/i18n.html